# Retirar lupa do search em webkit

Tags: html5, css3

como retirar essa lupa azul que aparece nos navegadores OPERA e Chrome ?

[image: Exemplo]

Já tentei `-webkit-appearance: none` porém nada ocorre.

```
.search input[type="search"] {
width: 170px; 
height: 27px; 
background: #fff url('images/search.png') no-repeat left; 
border: 2px #5473b9; 
border-radius:  5px; 
color: #000; 
padding-left: 20px;  
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: tenta isso aqui, http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/M8Azh/

Comment: VLW, deu certo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset para o `input[type=search]`

***CSS***

```
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance:textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

Você pode ver o resultado nesta **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/M8Azh/)**

Fonte: [Link](http://priyanksharma.com/code-snippets/resetting-html5-search-input-in-webkit/)